# Something WRONG

Tags: email, paypal

i was  recived  a e-mail from PP to my  e-mail  : igordimitrov1@abv.bg   at  11.04.2015 07:51 GMT+2 , where  is  writted  something about  my ACC  &  my   Credit  Card in your Web .
The  Problem : 
I was never registrated in your Web ( PayPal) by  MYSELF  and  by  this  e-mail : igordimitrov1@abv.bg this is my  1st  visiting when i read your sended e-mail. 
I don't know  WHO try to use my  e-mail  / credit  card  but  i  pleased you to punish  this  man and to DEL his/her profil in PayPal with  my  e-mail 
Thank You .

Comment: Sounds like it's just a spam phishing/malware e-mail. Ignore, do not click links or open attachments. If you already have done either of those, run a full virus scan immediately. Note that this site (Stack Overflow) is not affiliated with PayPal in any way, and does not take payment from its users.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a fake email which had nothing to do with this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be a good idea to contact PayPal about the matter to ensure your information is still secure. For good measure, you may want to consider a password change too.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive an email that appears to be from PayPal, forward it (as an attachment, if possible) to spoof@paypal.com.  PayPal will review it and let you know whether or not the email is genuine.